# I want a dynamic static field

Tags: c#, dynamic

I've got a class A with a public field b

```
class A
{
    public static string b;
}
```

but now I want to make b `dynamic` so I call it anything. So I can make the class a `DynamicObject`

```
class A : DynamicObject
{
}
```

but I the compiler doesn't let me now call `A.dynamicThing` cos I have to instantiate A as dynamic.

How can I mangle c# further to make this work?

Comment: What's wrong with `public static dynamic b;`? I am not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem - `A.dynamicThing` works for me regardless of whether I subclass from `DynamicObject` or not, I don't see how inheriting from `DynamicObject` is related to your problem?

Comment: I don't just want to do `public static dynamic b;` I want to put what ever I want in there hence subclassing `DynamicObject`, `A.dynamicThing` gives me `A does not contain a definition for dynamicThing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't belive you're going to find a way to make this work. It's not just the DynamicObject that makes things work. The declaration as a variable of the "dynamic" data type is what tells the compiler to actually *use* the DynamicObject base to resolve the member access. With static access direct to the class, you don't have that. So I really just don't think this is going to work in C# unless that changes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand now - the closest you can get is by using an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) :

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.somethinghere = "bar";
foo.dynamicThing = "baz";
```

**Edit:**

I don't think its possible to re-route the access to a *static property* of a class
to an expando object if the name of the property does not match - how would the compiler know that that's what you meant to do? You are getting a compile time error after all, not a runtime error.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> When a field, method, property, event,
>   operator, or constructor declaration
>   includes a static modifier, it
>   declares a static member. In addition,
>   a constant or type declaration
>   implicitly declares a static member.
>   Static members have the following
>   characteristics:

```
 When a static member M is referenced in a member-access (Section 7.5.4) 
 of the form E.M, E must denote a type containing M.
 ...
```

Comment: i don't want to instantiate though. I want to do EXPANDOOBJECT.x

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible right now with .NET 4

more information in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/10/23/using-c-dynamic-to-call-static-members.aspx).

Comment: If I understand correctly that article talks about accessing static properties on a given type using a dynamic object  - not exactly matches OP's question

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FakeDynamicMethodInvoker : DynamicObject
{
    // your code here
}
public class FakeDynamicWrapper<T>
{
    static FakeDynamicWrapper()
    {
        DynamicStaticField = (dynamic)new FakeDynamicMethodInvoker();
    }
    public static T DynamicStaticField{ get; set; }
}
public class RealClassWithDynamicStaticField: FakeDynamicWrapper<dynamic>
{

}
```

somewhere in a code:

```
RealClassWithDynamicStaticField.DynamicStaticField.AnyMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't let you really rename variables to some dynamic name at runtime.  Your question is mangled.

If you are wanting variable b to have a dynamic object at runtime, then use the **dynamic** keyword.

Example:

```
dynamic b = GetBValue();
b.SomeOperation(); // the type of "b" will be evaluated/chosen at runtime.
```

Comment: I dropped the field b in class A when I transformed it to a DynamicObject

Answer (score 0):

Old question but worth to answer :)

Static constructors are the answer to these problems.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static dynamic StaticDynamicObject;

    static MyClass()
    {
        StaticDynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();
        StaticDynamicObject.Prop = "woohoo!";
    }
}
```