# Is it possible to bound to any dynamic properties of a class some behavior?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I would like to define a dynamic class like it follows:

```
dynamic LocalizationHelper;

string s = LocalizationHelper.View1_Question;
```

it should accomplish the following task:

```
string s = Resource.ResourceManager.GetString("View1_Question", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag(Config.Language)
```

Is it possible so achieve something similar?

ps: i cannot do simply `Resource.View1_Question` because I've set the resources not to produce the c# code for doing that. And also I'm interested in the general solution. Not only for localization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overide [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and implement `TryGetMember`.

#### Usage

```
var s = LocalizationHelper.Instance.View1_Question; 
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

#### DynamicObject

```
class LocalizationHelper:DynamicObject
{
     static private dynamic inst = null;
     public static dynamic Instance {
        get {
            return inst ?? (inst = new LocalizationHelper());
        }
     }

     public override bool TryGetMember(
        GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

        result = Resource.ResourceManager.GetString(name);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good solution to add `.Instance`. One single issue: use `return inst ?? (inst = new LocalizationHelper);` to only create a single instance of the class.

Comment: very nice this solution: return inst ?? (inst = new LocalizationHelper()); +1

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Inherit your `LocalizationHelper` class from `DynamicObject` and override the `TryGetMember` method.

The `TryGetMember` method looks like this:

```
public virtual bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out Object result)
```

The `binder.Name` will tell you what property by name did the caller ask for, so you can then look up that key in your localization dictionary and return the value by setting the `out Object result`.

Answer (score 2):

A dynamic static field or property [doesn't seem to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445934/261050).

You can use a static property, but you will have to write out all properties that you would like.

```
public static class LocalizationHelper {
    public static string View1_Question {
        get { return Resource.ResourceManager.GetString("View1_Question", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag(Config.Language)); }
    }
}

var q1 = LocalizationHelper.View1_Question;
```